# How to achieve this style of digital paint?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, illustration, procreate

I would like to know to in which way can I achive this style? Adobe Illustrator or Photoshop/procreate?

As you can see, it is looks like pen markers with Playing with pressure.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you intend to post an image

Comment: ermm.. use a white brush on a white canvas maybe? `:)`

Comment: Sorry :)
I added the pictures now!

Comment: Looks kind of like fabric markers.. nothing digital at all.

Comment: But its must be printed, yea? its a t-shirt. So maybe self draw and scanning?

Comment: any modern bitmap painting software that comes to mind can produce a result like this, in Photoshop it would be a brush with wet edges to imitate the marker look and a brush with canvas texture for the grunge in the middle

Comment: There are markers *specifically* designed to "paint" on fabric.. so no it doesn't *have* to be printed. To me, it appears to be drawn directly on the fabric. The overall translucency in some areas leads me to believe there's no printing here at all - silkscreen or otherwise. I could, of course, be incorrect.